# Bisimulation in state transition system

Tags: algorithm, graph, partitioning, state-machine, automata

I have a labelled transition system (the one to the left in the picture below)

[image]

As can be seen from the picture, the two transition systems are 'equivalent'.

So I want to transform the one on the left to the one on the right. I know this is called bisimulation contraction (partition refinement), and I have found some [lecture slides](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/courses/lai0506/LAI11.pdf) explaining what the algorithm is like (which also includes some Haskell code), but I don't really understand how to do it.

I am trying to use the algorithm in JavaScript.

I have an array of nodes S and an array of edges R

```
N = [
  { id: 'n1', propositions: 'p' },
  { id: 'n2', propositions: 'p' },
  { id: 'n3', propositions: 'q' },
  { id: 'n4', propositions: 'q' },
]

R = [
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n2', label: 'pi_1' },
  { source: 'n2', target: 'n3', label: 'pi_2' },
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n4', label: 'pi_2' },
}
```

In the algorithm, it says that I should initially create a partition with all the same valuations, so the initial partition has two subblocks:

```
initial_partition = {
  'p': ['n1', 'n2'],
  'q': ['n3', 'n4']
}
```

Now I need to partition each block into subblocks based on their relations.

But how do I do this and how do I end up with the one to the left (i.e. when do I delete some of the nodes)?

I have found this [StackExchange question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19047/simple-bisimulation-algorithm) and this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisimulation), but it does not help me to fully understand it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?